# How to define model specification file?

Tags: jhipster

Kindly help on below error, I am getting some model specification, I am not sure on how to define one.

#### JHipster JDL file content

```
application {
  config {
    baseName myApp,
    applicationType monolith,
    packageName com.myapp,
    authenticationType jwt,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql,
    clientFramework angular
    enableSwaggerCodegen true
  }
  entities *
}

// One to One 
entity Product { name String }
entity Origin { name String}
relationship OneToOne { Product to Origin }


// Many to One 
entity Rating { name String }
entity Movie { name String }
relationship ManyToOne { Rating to Movie }



// One to Many
entity Customer { name String }
entity Address { name String  }
relationship OneToMany {  Customer to Address }


// Many to Many
entity Car { name String }
entity Owner { name String }
relationship ManyToMany { Car to Owner }
```

#### Error

After build is success, I tried below `./mvnw`, and got below error even though app is running fine...

```
2021-06-02 14:50:24.334 DEBUG 574 --- [  restartedMain] Validator                                : ERROR [ModelSpecification.spec] At least one type of specification is required
2021-06-02 14:50:24.337 DEBUG 574 --- [  restartedMain] Validator                                : ERROR [ModelSpecification.spec] At least one type of specification is required
2021-06-02 14:50:24.342 DEBUG 574 --- [  restartedMain] Validator                                : ERROR [ModelSpecification.spec] At least one type of specification is required
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really an error  as it is logged at DEBUG level. Although it's confusing, you can ignore it.

It's a known issue that will be fixed in next release 7.1.0, see  https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/13835